# Jquery append() is not appending as expected

Tags: jquery, append

So I have the following div

```
<div id="object_list">
```

I want to append a list and items into it.  So I run the following jquery

```
       $("#object_list").empty();
       $("#object_list").append('<ul');
       $("#object_list").append(list.contents());
       $("#object_list").append('</ul>');
```

After that code runs, #object_list looks like this

```
<div id="object_list">
  <ul></ul>
  ...list.contents() elements
</div>
```

Even after debugging, if I do another `$("#object_list").append('<ul>');` all I get is an added `<ul>` after the `</ul>`.  Why is jquery not appending to the html AFTER the list.contents(), but is going before it?

Comment: Perhaps not as expected, but as documented.  jQuery appends a complete element, not literal HTML.

Comment: Both answers worked, but could only mark one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append doesn't simply append tags, it actually appends elements. In your case you want to append list items to an unordered list that gets appended to your div.

Do:

```
$('<ul>').appendTo('#object_list').append(list.contents());
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you keep appending to "object_list" when you are meaning to append items to the list itself.  (as an aside, you aren't closing your UL instantiation tag either)

Try something like this:

```
var $list = $("<ul></ul>");
$list.append("<li>Something 1</li>");
$list.append("<li>Something 2</li>");
$list.append("<li>Something 3</li>");

$("#object_list").append($list);
```